Google Cloud - Set default retry for Cloud function in cloudbuild
I want to know if there's a way to configure the "Retry on failure" trigger policy directly in the Cloud Function's yaml.
As for now I found docs about Workflows or to simply flag it from the UI (which I did).
My doubt is if I deploy again and again my CF, this flag will be lost since it's not in the cloudbuild.yaml, where I configured my topic subscription.
This is my cloud build:
steps:
- name: 'build-step'
  args:
  - gcloud
  - functions
  - deploy
  - my-cf-name
  - --region=europe
  - --source=.
  - --trigger-topic=my-topic-name
  - --runtime=python310
  - --entry-point=my-entry-point
  - --timeout=540s
  - --env-vars-file=env.yaml
  - --service-account=my-service@account

Any tip will be appreciated, thank you.

This flag probably? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--retry
--retry
If specified, then the function will be retried in case of a failure.

Hi @MrThompson , yes you're right :) I was looking at the docs https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema and not seeing the flag made me think I couldn't set it inthere. Also, FYI, I re-deployed the CF without changing the cloudbuild to test it and I confirm the flag set from UI resetted. Now it works as supposed. If you want to post your comment, I'll accept it as answer

Glad that it help. I'll post it as a comment then.

You can try to use the --retry flag.
Docs are here
